# IE 10 will not open my web page image on top left of screen

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer

For some reason IE10 will not open the image in the tope left of my webpage. Chrome and Firefox have no issues. Here's the code for the table that includes the images. The image 'han' shows up as a single vertical line of pixels 196px high. :

```
<table style="width:100%" align = "center">
<tr>
<td>
<img src= "images/han.jpg" height = "196" width "304">
<p class = "co">Find your target first.</p>
</td>
<td>
<img src = "images/logo.gif" height = "294" width ="582" >
<br>
<p class ="co">So what's the bag limit on womp rats anyway?</p>
<td>
<img src = "images/greedo.jpg" height = "196" width = "304">
<p class = "co">Bad table fare.</p>
</td></tr></table>
```

It's got to be something really obvious that I am missing here. Every page has the same error.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle that demonstrates this? Note you're missing a closing td tag after the logo image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might or might not be the reason (as UnknownFury said, a jsfiddle reproducing the issue would help), but it looks like you're missing a `=` between `width` and its value.

You have: `<img src= "images/han.jpg" height = "196" width "304">`

It should be: `<img src= "images/han.jpg" height = "196" width="304">`

If the former works in any browser, it's by chance and due to browsers trying their best to correct invalid HTML for you.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said...."got to be something really obvious"...I was simply missing the "=" sign. Even the debugger said "Hey dude you're missing ="...I think your eyes get trained to see it after doing it so much even though it's not there. Thanks for the help people.